# AS3 Instance Name of a custom class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to get the instance name from a dropTarget of an object.

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import com.components.DragDropBucket;

var circle:Sprite = new Sprite();
circle.graphics.beginFill(0xFFCC00);
circle.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 40);
var target:Array = new Array();

target[0] = new Sprite();
target[0].graphics.beginFill(0xCCFF00);
target[0].graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
target[0].name = "target1";

target[1] = new Sprite();
target[1].graphics.beginFill(0xCCFF00);
target[1].graphics.drawRect(0, 200, 100, 100);
target[1].name = "target2";

var testv:DragDropBucket = new DragDropBucket("test", 500, 500, 175, 40,false);
testv.name ="test2";
var test:DragDropBucket = new DragDropBucket("test", 0, 0, 175, 40,true);

addChild(target[0]);
addChild(target[1]);
addChild(circle);

addChild(testv);
addChild(test);


circle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDown) 

function mouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void {
    circle.startDrag();
}
circle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseReleased);

function mouseReleased(event:MouseEvent):void {
    circle.stopDrag();
    trace(circle.dropTarget.name);
}
```

DragDropBucket is a custom class that extends Sprite Class.

So when I execute this code, when I drop the circle to `target[0]` or `target[0]` it successfully output "target1" and "target2".

Meanwhile when im drop the circle to testv object, the program output its name as instance#

Yet when I execute this code

```
trace(testv.name);
```

It prints "test2" well, no instance# or anything.

I'm not understand what is happening here, since DragDropBucket Class only extending the Sprite class and have nothing fancy. Maybe someone here can enlighten me, Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that circle.dropTarget exactly testv? Check some key properties to be sure. Maybe it's really drops to another object: test, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DragDropBucket class is not different of a library class. It's the same logic. There's an object contained in 'testv', your instance of DragDropBucket class, that is being detected as `dropTarget`.

```
function mouseReleased(event:MouseEvent):void {
    circle.stopDrag();
    trace(circle.dropTarget.name, circle.dropTarget.parent.name);
    // output : instance1, test2
}
```

If 'test2' is not the parent of 'instance1', that's its parent.parent, or more.

Comment: Awesome helloflash, i owe you one, I've been tinkering this thing since this morning.

After i edit the code to this
`function mouseReleased(event:MouseEvent):void {
    circle.stopDrag();
    trace("circle.dropTarget.name : "+circle.dropTarget.name);
 trace("circle.dropTarget.parent.name : "+circle.dropTarget.parent.name);
 trace("testv : "+testv.name);
}`
it show me a miracle 
Output :
circle.dropTarget.name : instance171
circle.dropTarget.parent.name : test2
testv : test2